# magento: Unknown column 'reminder.type', 'reminder.status'

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I try to solve an error that happens as soon im in 'sale -> bills' (backend) and set a filter critera and click to filter.

First happens nothing but after clicking around i get an error which is explaned in the 'report' folder text file:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'COALESCE(CONCAT(reminder.type,
>   reminder.status), '0')' in 'where clause'";i:1;s:5999:"#0
>   /web/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

As i know, someone installed and uninstalled some Plugins, maybe the error happens of this. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Daniel